# Exclude East Asian (CJK) characters from spell check

Tags: spell-checking

How can I make vim accept all CJK characters as correctly spelled while still having the spell check language set to English?

If it's easier, a rule to only check the spelling of Latin characters would work just as well in practice for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `:set spelllang+=cjk` ?

From `:help 'spelllang'`:

> If the name "cjk" is included East Asian characters are excluded from
>   spell checking.  This is useful when editing text that also has Asian
>   words.

That sounds exactly like what you're asking for.

Comment: The corresponding configuration for neovim is `vim.opt.spelllang = vim.opt.spelllang + "cjk"`.

Comment: @weakish Just to avoid confusing newer users it should be noted that you're referring to Lua configuration. The answer works as is for Neovim when using traditional vimrc.