# Exclude Greek unicode words from spell check

Tags: spell-checking

I would like vim spell to ignore words with Greek characters. Based on [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13239/exclude-east-asian-cjk-characters-from-spell-check), I thought it might work to write `:set spelllang+=cjk`, but that did nothing. Apparently that only works for East Asian characters. Is there a comparable setting for Greek characters?

Comment: What does `:help 'spelllang'` say?

Comment: FYI, `cjk` = **C**hinese **J**apanese **K**orean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run the following command:

```
syntax match greekword /\<[α-ωΑ-Ω]\+\>/ contains=@NoSpell
```

It makes that the words that match the pattern (i.e.: are made entirely of Greek letters) are not checked for spelling error.

If you would like to have it automatically for all the LaTeX file (filetype: `tex`) you can add a dedicated syntax file to your configuration:

`~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/tex.vim`

With the following content:

```
syntax match greekword /\<[α-ωΑ-Ω]\+\>/ contains=@NoSpell
```

If you want to take all the [Greek letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_script_in_Unicode) you can do:

```
syntax match greekwork /[\u370-\u3ff\u1d26-\u1d6a\u1dbf\u1f00-\u1ffc\u213c-\u213f\u3382-\u33bc\uab65\U1d6a8-\U1d7cb]/ contains=@NoSpell
```

*Remark: to simplify the pattern some additional characters has been included.*

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work for me. Could it be because I am using `vimtex`, which does a lot of syntax highlighting and such?

Comment: Also: I am using neovim, in case that is relevant.

Comment: Do you confirm that when you have the LaTeX document in the buffer and you ran the Neovim command: `:syntax match greekword /\<[α-ωΑ-Ω]\+\>/ contains=@NoSpell` you still have the greek word with spelling error?

Comment: I have edited the solution such that it works automatically for all LaTeX files.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it again now, pasting in this exact command, and it still underlines the Greek words as if they were spelling errors.

Comment: Can you give an example of Greek word? Are they found by the following search `/\<[α-ωΑ-Ω]\+\>`?

Comment: Ah! That was the problem. That search only picks out words that contain *un-accented* Greek characters exclusively -- very few. Here are some examples of Greek words that I am working with:  `Ὁ δὲ ἡμέτερος χρυσὸς`, `ποιεῖ`, etc. Is there a way to include accented characters too? i.e., Greek characters that have ᾽ ῾ ῀ ´ ` ῏ ῟ ῎ or ῍ on them? Also, maybe it would be good to make the search match even when other characters are included too, since not all Greek punctuation characters will necessarily be recognized as such by vim (e.g., the Greek semicolon `·`).

Comment: Oh, and it also needs to deal with iota subscripts `ι`: `ῃ ᾔ ῳ ᾧ` etc.

Comment: Do you know to update the solution or do you need help for that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to update the solution.

Comment: I have updated the solution to take into account more Greek letters (hopefully all of them). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That did it -- thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)